# How to implement Exception handing for both Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Python 3 changed the syntax of catching Exceptions. How can I make my script compatible for both versions? I know the way to detect Python version but do I need to use `If-else` check and repeat entire `try-catch` block?

Comment: You can use the `except Blah as x` syntax directly in Python 2.7, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yep!! thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.6 and 2.7 support the new `except Exception as e:` syntax, just like Python 3.

---

If you're unfortunate enough to use long-dead Python 2 versions 2.5, or even (gasp) 2.4, it is still "possible", but you must resort to some awful hacks like

```
>>> import sys
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...     e = sys.exc_info()[1]
...     # process e
...     del e
```